# Is $\{\langle M \rangle \mid \exists K \forall w\; \text{M(w) halt with less than K steps}\} \in RE$?

Tags: computability, turing-machines

Is $L=\{\langle M \rangle \mid \exists K \forall w\; \text{M(w) halt with less than K steps}\} \in RE$ ?

I can prove that $L \notin coRE$, but I don't know what to do about $RE$...

($L \in coRE \Rightarrow \overline{L} \in RE$
By find reduction $f$ from $\overline{HP}$ to $\overline{L}$ we show that $L \notin coRE$.
Let $f(M,w)=M_w$ such that for each input $x$, $M_w$ do:
1. Run M with input w
2. Accept
With this function $\langle M,w \rangle \in \overline{HP} \Leftrightarrow M_w \in \overline{L}$ )

Comment: $RE$ seems to be the set of all recursively enumerable languages, but you ought to define $HP$ here, even if one can reverse-engineer what it must be by studying your proof closer. Names of particular problems are less well standardized than names of _classes_ of problems, and each author tends to make up his own. So by assuming that the reader knows the particular nomenclature you use, you will be excluding many readers who would otherwise be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Whether $M$ halts in less than $K$ steps can only depend on the first $K$ symbols of the input -- the machine will not have time to move further right anyway. So for each $K$ it is enough to check whether $M$ halts quickly for every $w$ of length $\le K$.

Comment: Thanks!  
Let $U$ to be Non-deterministic turing machine. What U(M) does is:  
1. Guess k
2. For every input $w$ such $|w| <= k$ run M(k) for k steps. If M halt for all inputs, accept. Else, reject.