# Is $\{\langle M \rangle \mid \exists P \;\text{(p is polynom)}\; \forall w\; \text{M(w) halt with less than p(|w|) steps}\} \in RE$?

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, turing-machines

Is $L=\{\langle M \rangle \mid \exists P \;\text{(p is polynom)}\;  \forall w\; \text{M(w) halt with less than p(|w|) steps}\} \in RE$?

I can prove that $L \notin coRE$, but I don't know what to do about $RE$...

The question is very similar to the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1852952/is-langle-m-rangle-mid-exists-k-forall-w-textmw-halt-with-less-tha), but this problem looks really harder, and I have no idea how to do it, since there is no finite set that I can check single polynom.

Comment: I guessed it, and tried to prove, but without success....

Comment: Note that the word is _"polynomial"_ (this is both a noun and an adjective).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For some $M_0$ and $w_0$ consider the function

$$ f(n) = \begin{cases} \bot & \text{ if $M_0(w_0)$ halts in exactly $n$ steps} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

Does $L$ contain the machine that computes $f$ in the straightforward way?

Comment: I didn't get it... What is the input of this machine? $M_0$ and $w_0$?

Comment: @Dubon: The machine implements the functon $f$, whose input, as defined here, is $n$.

Comment: Ok, now I confused. Why it's not working for $L$ from previous question?

Comment: @Dubon: The machine being constructed here is never in the previous question's $L$. More precisely if $M_0(w_0)$ doesn't halt, then it can take arbitrarily long for the machine to compute $f(n)$ for large $n$, so no $K$ will work.

Comment: Thanks! I just now got it.